# Don't ask for a derived variable in cookiecutter

Tags: cookiecutter

This is my `cookiecutter.json` file:

```json
{
    "day": "1",
    "directory_name": "day-{{ cookiecutter.day }}"
}
```

Now I only want to be prompted for the `day`, but not for the `directory_name` which is derived from it. How do I get that to happen?

The documentation for [`no_input`](https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/suppressing_prompts.html) is less than helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `no-input` option is general option, allowing you to use all the defaults and skipping the questions overall.

What you need is a [private variable](https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/private_variables.html)

```json
{
    "day": "1",
    "__directory_name": "day-{{ cookiecutter.day }}"
}
```

Comment: Wow. How did I miss that!?

Comment: :)  Happens to everyone.